# QProcess doesn't work with "~" symbol

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qprocess

I want to use QProcess to launch an executable file, assuming it is located in the home directory.

The following code works:

```
    QProcess process;
    QString cmd = qgetenv("HOME") + "/executableFile";
    process.start(cmd);
```

However, it will not work if I use "~" to stand for home directory:

```
    QString cmd = "~/executableFile";
```

Maybe it is a silly question, but I really want to know why.
Hope to get your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~` is a special character handled by the shell.

```
$ echo ~
/home/jbm
```

But when you use a QProcess, there's no such thing as a shell to launch your process (just an environment, which is not the same), hence the "~" is not handled, but rather seen as a character literal that would actually be part of the path to your executable.